# Which is the proper way to calculate average speed.

Tags: physics, average

Let's say we have a graph, a distance-time graph, and there are couple points on the graph. The points are connected to each other with different slopes, so with different speeds between the points.

What is the correct way of calculationg speed?

Method 1

Subtract the initial distance from the final distance from the **whole graph** and divide by time.

Method 2

Subtract the initial distance from final distance of **each segment** of speed. Then divide each segment difference by time, abd average them all together.

I keep insisting on method 2 and my teacher on method 1. Which is more correct? By the way they produce similar but different results.

Comment: Your method is incorrect unless you properly weight the average.  Going 20 mph for one hour will influence the average speed more than going 100 mph for 5 minutes.  So for instance, in that example the average would be: $\frac{60\cdot20 + 5\cdot 100}{65} \approx 26$.

Comment: Also, do you mean average _speed_ or average _velocity_?  There is a difference.  Method 1 correctly computes the average _velocity_ but _not_ the average speed.

Comment: Isn't velocity same thing as speed, only difference being velocity has direction, which really doesnt matter?

Comment: Say a dog was running around a circular track with length 10 meters, and the dog took 20 seconds to come back to the start line, so that the final position is equal to the initial position. Then the average **velocity** would be 0, since (final position)-(initial position)=0, but the average **speed** would be 0.5 m/s, since speed is (total distance traveled)/(time taken).

Comment: Assuming this actually _is_ a "distance"-time graph then the teacher's method would be correct.  Because if it _is_ a distance-time graph then the graph must be a [monotonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) _non-decreasing_ function.  On the other hand, if it's a _displacement-time_ graph then you have to take into account regions where the graph "turns around" (i.e. decreases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a function $f(x)$, its average value on an interval $[a, b]$ is given as;
>   $$f_{avg} =\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

Suppose the given distance function respect to time ($t$) is given by $s(t)$.
Then the velocity would be given as $v(t)=s'(t)$

Now if we were to calculate the average velocity, we would compute;
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b v(t)dt$$

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b v(t)dt=\frac{1}{b-a}[s(t)]_a^b$$

which is equal to $$\frac{s(b)-s(a)}{b-a}$$

Implication: Subtract initial position from the final position and divide it by whole time. So method 1 would be correct for calculating the average **velocity**.